# Rails model relationships not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, associations, has-many, belongs-to

I am new to rails and I am having trouble getting my model relationships to work properly.  I can't seem to get the relationship between posts and comments to work.  When I call @comments = @post.comments, I don't get an error, I just get an empty array.  Below are some console logs, my database scheme, and my models.

Thanks in advance for all the help.

```
Testing Posts
>> p = Post.first


DEPRECATION WARNING: Calling #default_scope without a block is deprecated. For example   instead of `default_scope where(color: 'red')`, please use `default_scope { where(color: 'red') }`. (Alternatively you can just redefine self.default_scope.). (called from <class:Post> at /Users/addisonhuddy/code/thatHigh/app/models/post.rb:6) 
Post Load (4.3ms)  SELECT "posts".* FROM "posts" ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 1 
=> #<Post id: 517, post: "ea doloribus ut rerum repellat in nostrum dolores q...", user_id: 27, created_at: "2013-11-13 23:43:24", updated_at: "2013-11-13 23:43:24", slug: "ea-doloribus-ut-rerum-repellat-in-nostrum-dolores-q..."> 
>> p.comments 
Comment Load (3.6ms)  SELECT "comments".* FROM "comments" WHERE "comments"."post_id" = $1  [["post_id", 517]] 
 => #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy []>
```

Testing Users,Posts, and Comments

```
>> u = User.first
User Load (1.4ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
=> #<User id: 1, email: "myemail@myemail.com", encrypted_password:
>> u.comments
Comment Load (3.5ms)  SELECT "comments".* FROM "comments" WHERE "comments"."user_id" = $1  [["user_id", 1]]
=> #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy []>
>> c = Comment.first
Comment Load (1.4ms)  SELECT "comments".* FROM "comments" ORDER BY "comments"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
=> #<Comment id: 1, comment: "dolore\net\nlaborum\nmolestias\ncum\nab\nexercitationem\nc...", post_id: nil, user_id: 2, created_at: "2013-11-13 23:43:06", updated_at: "2013-11-13 23:43:06">
>> c.user
User Load (1.1ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 2]]
=> #<User id: 2, email: "jazmyne_streich@gulgowski.name", encrypted_password: "$2a$10$7uBKw9GfirIKeaQleHAq7uYNpFJf9FECsDvB.vqi0um9...", reset_password_token: nil, reset_password_sent_at: nil, remember_created_at: nil, sign_in_count: 0, current_sign_in_at: nil, last_sign_in_at: nil, current_sign_in_ip: nil, last_sign_in_ip: nil, created_at: "2013-11-13 23:43:06", updated_at: "2013-11-13 23:43:06", username: "destinee.ritchie">>> c.post
=> nil
```

Scheme

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20131113195400) do

  # These are extensions that must be enabled in order to support this database
  enable_extension "plpgsql"

  create_table "comments", force: true do |t|
    t.text     "comment"
    t.integer  "post_id"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  add_index "comments", ["post_id"], name: "index_comments_on_post_id", using: :btree
  add_index "comments", ["user_id"], name: "index_comments_on_user_id", using: :btree

  create_table "friendly_id_slugs", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "slug",                      null: false
    t.integer  "sluggable_id",              null: false
    t.string   "sluggable_type", limit: 50
    t.string   "scope"
    t.datetime "created_at"
  end

  add_index "friendly_id_slugs", ["slug", "sluggable_type", "scope"], name: "index_friendly_id_slugs_on_slug_and_sluggable_type_and_scope", unique: true, using: :btree
  add_index "friendly_id_slugs", ["slug", "sluggable_type"], name: "index_friendly_id_slugs_on_slug_and_sluggable_type", using: :btree
  add_index "friendly_id_slugs", ["sluggable_id"], name: "index_friendly_id_slugs_on_sluggable_id", using: :btree
  add_index "friendly_id_slugs", ["sluggable_type"], name: "index_friendly_id_slugs_on_sluggable_type", using: :btree

  create_table "posts", force: true do |t|
    t.text     "post"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.string   "slug"
  end

  add_index "posts", ["user_id"], name: "index_posts_on_user_id", using: :btree

  create_table "users", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "email",                  default: "", null: false
    t.string   "encrypted_password",     default: "", null: false
    t.string   "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer  "sign_in_count",          default: 0
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.string   "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.string   "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.string   "username"
  end

  add_index "users", ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true, using: :btree
  add_index "users", ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true, using: :btree

end
```

User model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts
  has_many :comments

  validates_presence_of :username
  validates_uniqueness_of :username, if: -> { self.username.present? }

  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :token_authenticatable, :confirmable,
  # :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
end
```

Post model

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :comments
  belongs_to :user

  default_scope order("created_at DESC")

  validates_presence_of :post

  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :post, use: :history

  def should_generate_new_friendly_id?
    new_record?
  end
end
```

Comment model

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Comment: There's nothing about your console logs that demonstrates any problem at all?

Answer (score 0):

You are getting an empty array for `post.comments` because you most likely don't have data in your comments table for post_id 517

Also your user model should look like this

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts
  has_many :comments, :through => :posts
end
```

User and Comment are not associated direcly. Have a look at the [documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association) for more information on has_many :through associations

Answer (score 0):

1-check your database associations meaning you have a column for associating the two tables in each table Users for example must have a comment_id and comments must have User_id (if you don't have a foreign key the association won't work) and do review your migrations sometimes it's partially damaged for whatever reason.

2- Try adding any attribute for the connection between both and like user.comment.id and see what comes up if nothing comes up for any attribute then it's the connection if one attribute comes up and the other not then it's a problem with the naming of this attribute check the names in your database (Case sensitive) 
3- try restarting the server one time i had this problem and it was simply going crazy for no reason restart the server and try adding different stuff and then redo it and it might work.

Hope that helps